# Updating to Ember 3: Expecting 'CLOSE', got 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli

Before upgrading Ember, the following code worked:

```
{{each invitation in model itemViewClass="invitation" itemController="invitation"}}
```

However, due to the Ember.JS changes, (see http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-in-code-syntax-for-code-each-code), I had to change it to:

```
{{each invitation itemViewClass="invitation" itemController="invitation" as |model|}}
```

Now I get the error:

```
"Expecting 'CLOSE', got 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are upgrading to 2.0 and `itemController` and `itemViewClass` were deprecated in 1.13.  That being said, the `each` helper in a non-block form without those two properties likely wouldn't be useful, so likely doesn't support non-block anymore.

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_notable-deprecations-in-1-13

You'll want to convert the `itemController` and `itemViewClass` into a component and use a block `each`

```
{{#each model as |invitation|}}
   {{invitation-thingy invitation=invitation}}
{{/each}}
```